# Retrieve ISBN from eBay listing via Shopping API

Tags: ebay-api, isbn

I'm trying to use the eBay shopping API to try and retrieve the ISBNs from listings for books. I already have the eBay IDs for the listings which I'm interested in. Likely that most will have the ISBNs included in the Item Specifics for the listing (some won't, these can be disregarded).
One would therefore assume that retrieving the Item Specifics from the API would give the ISBN as a value, but it appears that the output gives pretty much everything *apart* from the ISBN. For example, the following API request gives lots of interesting detail about the listing, apart from the ISBN itself:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=MYAPPID&siteid=1&version=897&ItemID=EBAYID&IncludeSelector=ItemSpecifics
```

I haven't had much joy searching the API docs for a solution to getting this particular element from the listing - does anybody have a solution for this? Or if it simply isn't possible to get the ISBN via the API cleanly, is there an alternative method? (This is for very small scale personal use.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISBN, UPC, EAN and suchlike come under the `productID` field.

This field is returned by using the `Details` value of `IncludeSelector`. So the url you would want is:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=MYAPPID&siteid=1&version=897&ItemID=EBAYID&IncludeSelector=Details
```

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Response.Item.ProductID

**EDIT**:

To get the ISBN form a catalogue product you need to use the `productID` value to make a request to the [Product API](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/product/CallRef/index.html).

You need to call `getProductDetails` with the input:

```
 <productDetailsRequest>
    <productIdentifier>
       <ePID>91515717</ePID>
    </productIdentifier>
    <datasetPropertyName>ISBN</datasetPropertyName>
 </productDetailsRequest>
```

You can use `ISBN10` or `ISBN13` as the value of `datasetPropertyName` depending on which one you want.

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=getProductDetails&SECURITY-APPNAME=APPID&SERVICE-VERSION=1.3.0&productDetailsRequest.productIdentifier.ePID=REFERENCE&productDetailsRequest.datasetPropertyName=ISBN
```

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/product/CallRef/getProductDetails.html

Comment: It seems that this returns the ReferenceID in the productID field by default, can this be overridden to return ISBN?

Comment: The method described in the edit seems to be working perfectly - thank you.